# Passing character pointers into a function and dynamically allocating memory

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dynamic-allocation

Student.h

```
class Student
{
 private:
      char m_sHouse[64];
 public:
 Student(void);
 ~Student(void);
 void getHouse(char *hName);
 void setHouse(char *hName);
}
```

Student.cpp

```
 void Student::setHouse(char *hName)
 {
    strcpy(m_sHouse, hName);
 }

 void Student::getHouse(char *hName)
 {
     if (m_sHouse != NULL)
     {
        hName = new char[strlen(m_sHouse)+1];
        strcpy(hName, m_sHouse);
     }
 }
```

In main:

```
 student.getHouse(house);
 if (strcmp(house, "house") == 0)
     cout <<"\tCorrectly returned the student house: " << house<< endl;
```

`setHouse(char *hName)` sets `student->m_sHouse` equal to "house".

My question:

When inside `getHouse(char *hName)`, it acts as it should, setting `hName` to "house". but when control is passed out of the function, my dynamically allocated memory is deallocated, so when I strcmp in main, my program crashes (I end up comparing a NULL pointer).

Comment: 1. It's not deallocated. 2. Don't do this.

Comment: The given answers will solve this problem, but may I ask why you need to do this? Using `strcpy` in C++ is usually frowned upon, since you're mixing different styles. Have you tried working with `std:string`s?

Comment: While it is important for you to understand why your code is crashing, it is better to switch to C++ strings to avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: I need to do it this way because my teacher is old. He understands that using strings is the way to go, but the way he sees it, we may have to work with either old code, or old programmers stuck in their ways, so he wants us to be comfortable using kernigan and ritchie character arrays.

Comment: Someone working on Dr. Coleman's assignment I see.

Comment: mmhmm. only two weeks late too.

Comment: @Nick Your teacher is incredibly pessimistic, I see.

Comment: @Nick If you need help, I'd be glad to help out. By the way, this is Rich.

Comment: I'll find you. I'm assuming your in my class now?

Comment: @Nick Indeed. I can help before/after class, if you have a preferred time.

Comment: either works for me. i'll probably be there early, if thats cool w/ you. thanks man :D

Comment: @Nick I should be around at ~4:30.

Comment: Also, if someone has answered your question, plea see mark it as such by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, we did not set a place to meet. On that note, I'm in the lounge like area right next to the classroom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nick, the proper solution is that you know that `hName` is already allocated by the user of the class (Dr. Coleman). You simply need to `strcpy` into the character array.

Simply put:

```
void Student::getHouse(char *hName)
{
  strcpy(hName, m_sHouse);
}
```

Comment: of course its the easy answer....appreciate it mate. other answers were correct, just not following the specific parameters the dr. coleman gave....then again, I didn't specify. see you in a few hours.

Answer (score 3):

You are  allocating new memory and assigning it to a local variable. Change your function to

```
 void Student::getHouse(char **hName)
 {
     if (m_sHouse != NULL)
     {
        *hName = new char[strlen(m_sHouse)+1];
        strcpy(*hName, m_sHouse);
     }
 }
```

This will change the address pointed to by the argument passed in to your function, not the copy of it

Comment: I understand that this will work, however, my teacher gave us extremely specific requirements when naming/defining class functions, because he grades by using his own main. he told us to specifically use the function prototype (if thats even what you call them when its a class function) `void getName(char *mName, char *wName);` so, i cant make a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `hname` is **a copy** of `house` (the pointer you have passed to `getHouse`). Inside that function you change `hname`, however, you are **not** changing the original `house`! To do that, you should either return the allocated memory:

```
char *Student::getHouse()
{
    char *hame = NULL;
    if (m_sHouse != NULL)
    {
        hName = new char[strlen(m_sHouse)+1];
        strcpy(hName, m_sHouse);
    }
    return hname;
}
```

and then

```
house = student.getHouse();
```

or give a pointer to this variable, so that it can be changed:

```
void Student::getHouse(char **hName)
{
    if (m_sHouse != NULL && hname != NULL)
    {
        *hName = new char[strlen(m_sHouse)+1];
        strcpy(*hName, m_sHouse);
    }
}
```

and then

```
student.getHouse(&house);
```

Similarly, you can give a reference to the house variable:

```
void Student::getHouse(char *&hName)
{
    if (m_sHouse != NULL)
    {
        hName = new char[strlen(m_sHouse)+1];
        strcpy(hName, m_sHouse);
    }
}
```

and then

```
student.getHouse(house);
```

The better solution however, would be to use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
void Student::getHouse(char *hName)
{
     if (m_sHouse != NULL)
     {
        hName = new char[strlen(m_sHouse)+1];
        strcpy(hName, m_sHouse);
     }
 }
```

This only modifies a copy of `hName` pointer and does not modify the original pointer. To modify it you need to pass a pointer to your pointer:

```
void Student::getHouse(char **hName)
{
     if (m_sHouse != NULL)
     {
        *hName = new char[strlen(m_sHouse)+1];
        strcpy(*hName, m_sHouse);
     }
 }
```

and call your function like this:

```
student.getHouse(&house);
```